# How to migrate NPM package to an organization @scope

Tags: node.js, npm

[NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/orgs/what-are-orgs) has recently introduced @scopes / organizations for the modules.  Is there a good way to migrate existing modules to the organization? Are there any tools for automating it for a large number of packages?  Does NPM support redirects, so that other software could still use the old name, yet get a notification that it should be updated?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can change your package.json from:

```
"name": "project-name"
```

to:

```
"name": "@scope/project-name"
```

and publish the package:

```
npm publish --access=public
```

**Update:** The `--access=public` argument is needed to make the scoped package public - otherwise it will be private by default. Instead of the command-line argument you can set `access` to `"public"` in the `publishConfig` section of your `package.json`:

```
"publishConfig": {
  "access": "public"
}
```

**(Thanks to [Danilo Bargen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284318/danilo-bargen) and [Greg Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130266/greg) for pointing it out in the comments!)**

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages

The npm doesn't support redirects from old names to new names but
you can deprecate the old package with:

```
npm deprecate <pkg>[@<version>] <message>
```

So that people who install the old version would be notified that they should install another package instead.

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/deprecate

Comment: The publish command should probably include the `--access=public` argument.

Comment: Or add `"publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },` to the package.json, otherwise it will be published as private by default

Comment: @DaniloBargen Good catch, thanks for pointing it out! I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this that doesn't involve renaming the package, is to go to the team settings in your organization on the npm website (there's a default team called "developers"). There's a button there to add an existing package to the team.

This way you actually transfer the package, instead of republishing it under a different name.

Comment: How come this doesn't work for packages that members published but are unscoped. Npm responds with "forbidden" when I try to add a package to the developer's team.

Comment: But this will won't redirect for all current users of the package, or will it?

Comment: I just tried this.  It doesn't transfer the package to the organisation, it just allows people in the organisation to publish changes to the original package.

Comment: In my case, the idea is to get it under the scope to help mitigate package confusion attacks. AFAICT just transferring ownership to the org wouldn't help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

One can give a team in a NPM organization access via the command:

```
npm access grant <read-only|read-write> <org:team> [<package>]
```

See "[Adding package access to a team using the CLI](https://docs.npmjs.com/managing-team-access-to-organization-packages#adding-package-access-to-a-team-using-the-cli)".

Alternatively, there is also a way to do this via the web UI. See "[Adding package access to a team on the web](https://docs.npmjs.com/managing-team-access-to-organization-packages#adding-package-access-to-a-team-on-the-web)".

Both ways seem to require admin permissions.

After one has given an organization team permissions, one can remove package access for the single users.

This can be either done via CLI:

```
npm owner rm <your-username> <package-name>
```

See "[npm-owner](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-owner)".

Or the web UI via the package settings.

Users, who are in a team that has access, still have access to the package, after they have been removed.