# Add an organisation as an owner of an NPM package

Tags: npm, scope, owner, npm-registry

I am looking to add an organisation as a user or transfer ownership of a package so that it appears in their 'packages' section.

Attempting to associate them via `npm add user *org registry name*` doesn't work, since they're an org and not a user.

Would the correct approach be for my company to [associate a scope with their registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope#associating-a-scope-with-a-registry) and then associating that scope with the package registry?

Can't find further information on how to achieve this seemingly simple task.

Comment: Think this Stack link might hold the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007471/how-to-migrate-npm-package-to-an-organization-scope

Answer (score 0):

You can't transfer an NPM package to an organization, but you can transfer it to an organization's team.

To do so, go to the org's packages page (`https://www.npmjs.com/settings/{ORG_NAME}/teams`) and select the team you want to grant access, then you can enter the package name and click "+ Add Existing Package".